# How to implement Row Level Security (RLS) on Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, row-level-security

Can we implement row level security on Mongo Db with node js or something else? Does it called as document level security on MongoDb? Does anyone have such an example or document about this?

Answer (score 4):

Nope, mongodb does not support that finely grained restrictions. The finest you can do is collection-level.

> So i asked this question if I can implement row level security specifically with the help of node.js, mongodb c#, entity framework vs..

Security features like this must be natively supported by the database. Application-side implementation will be unreliable and with poor performance.

Comment: Collection levet security grants users privileges for collections, i want to do this for not collections, only for each rows or each document in collections. So i asked this question if i can implement row level security specificly with the help of node js, mongodb c#, entity framework vs..